# Maintaining Android Footers

Tags: android, android-layout

This has been asked before but not answered.  In Android there is a very common component called a ListView.  ListViews can have headers and footers.   The listview provides an addFooter/removeFooter methods. The footer must be added/removed before the setAdapter is called.

Now the question is how to avoid resetting the adapter to make a change to the footer.  If the footer is added in the beginning, and you do not want to reset the adapter again and again for footer changes is there a way to reset the visibility on a footer.  GONE---VISIBLE-->GONE and have the footer update and redraw.  Is there any way to get the footer to redraw WITHOUT resetting the adapter?

Comment: So truth be told, if you look inside the Android source, the footer rules were broken in the original implementation and they kept it that way because so many things were built that way. You can add and remove footers at will after the adapter is set ;) Try it

Comment: I have tried it but there are things an go awry like null pointer exceptions and the like.  But lets say you just add one footer at the beginning, how can you get that footer to refresh (without resetting the adapter) with new setting like visibility etc.  This would solve a lot of issues if it could be done.

Comment: When you say resetting the adapter, do you mean, calling something like `notifyDataSetChanged()`? I think you should be able to still just update the footer like an other view. Change it's visibility if it's already added.

Comment: Thats fine.  I just don't want to do listView.setAdapter(adapter). notifyDataSetChanged().  I think that might still not be enough with footers but I will try and see.

Comment: I will have to test this.  I think it might not be enough although it is true that footers get converted to regular list items.  I will try this and report what I see.

Comment: Yeah I mean even if it is GONE, it will still count as a cell in the list, so if you use dividers, you will see a double divider. I would recommend just adding and removing the footer. just make sure an adapter is set the whole time.

Comment: Well what about adding one placeholder footer.  Only keep that one footer.  Add and remove the other footers from the placeholder?  So far I need to make sure that footer an be re-shown after it has been removed.

Comment: So far I not been able to get a footer to re-appear after setting its visibility to GONE.